# What am i doing wrong?, Am creating react app with, npx create-react-app app_name. but i keep getting thing unusual error

Tags: reactjs

C:\Users\user>npx create-react-app my-app-redux-demo

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\user\my-app-redux-demo.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\user\my-app-redux-demo\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@3.9.0 postinstall C:\Users\user\my-app-redux-demo\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js-pure@3.9.0 postinstall C:\Users\user\my-app-redux-demo\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\Users\user\my-app-redux-demo\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

- cra-template@1.1.2
- react-scripts@4.0.2
- react-dom@17.0.1
- react@17.0.1
  added 1903 packages from 722 contributors and audited 1906 packages in 463.186s

127 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Git repo not initialized Error: Command failed: git --version
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at execSync (child_process.js:647:15)
at tryGitInit (C:\Users\user\my-app-redux-demo\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:46:5)
at module.exports (C:\Users\user\my-app-redux-demo\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:283:7)
at [eval]:3:14
at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:131:20)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:297:38)
at Object. ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25) {
status: 1,
signal: null,
output: [ null, null, null ],
pid: 6444,
stdout: null,
stderr: null
}

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-zJmm08OqHoWE/tbPBA3EoM3NqC+jSXNrjmFOL793hAbIsvaQb1AGlZwyklCdorV7Smk99/CUEbGMX4WyYp9eOQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-zJmm08OqHoWE/tbPBA3EoM3NqC+jSXNrjmFOL793hAbIsvaQb1AGlZwyklCdorV7Smk99/CUEbGMX4WyYp9eOQ== but got sha512-bT3IYAdf9Eqxmgn6hiWRbSzk6tLXQqI9oMekX8vYrhnaMN7MK7A7uYzVR2dlbf0vqr5HvYW2DOV61NEoGJXTVQ==.
(180727 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/@testing-library%2fuser-event: Integrity verification failed for sha512-zJmm08OqHoWE/tbPBA3EoM3NqC+jSXNrjmFOL793hAbIsvaQb1AGlZwyklCdorV7Smk99/CUEbGMX4WyYp9eOQ== (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\cc\99\a6d3c3aa1e8584fed6cf040dc4a0cdcda82fa349736b8e614e2fbf778406c8b2f6906f5006959c3292509da2b57b4a693df7f09411b18c5f85b2629f5e39)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-19T14_10_23_648Z-debug.log
`npm install --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.11.4 @testing-library/react@^11.1.0 @testing-library/user-event@^12.1.10 web-vitals@^1.0.1` failed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the directory where you ran CRA doesn't allow initializing a git repo. Could it be read-only?. Try git init in a new directory in the same path and if it fails - troubleshoot that. Once it succeeds, CRA should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure that you have correctly installed `git` by following the installation process outlined on https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git.

After installing, you can confirm that `git` is installed by running `git --version` (what React is trying to do).  Currently, you will likely see an error trying to run this command as git is not installed.  Post-install, you should see a version number being displayed.

After installing `git`, run your `create-react-app` again.